# Can anyone identify this mushroom?

Tags: identification, cactus, mushrooms

I've had this cactus for over a decade. About a month ago I gave it some more soil. Tonight I noticed this mushroom growing next to it/ almost on it. I plucked it because it doesn't go there. Do I have any cause for concern? I assume it came in with the soil? The cactus looks normal for now.

[image: yellowish mushroom cap with darker orangy yellow spots]

[image: pale yellow stem]

Comment: Mushrooms like moisture. Keep your cactus drier.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which type of mushroom it is, but yes, you will have imported its mycelium (kind of like its roots) with the soil you added, and this is the fruiting body. You will likely get more mushrooms next year if not sooner, but they won't harm the cactus or you in any way, just remove them when they appear. I wouldn't recommend eating them, not sure if they're edible!